# ngRoute not directing to anything

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

So I'm trying to learn how to use Angulars routing, following tutorials online, and I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I have the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('gamersplane', ['controllers', 'ngCookies', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/pms/:box?', {
        controller: 'pmList'
    }).when('/pms', {
        controller: 'pmList'
    }).otherwise({
        controller: 'pmList'
    });
}])

var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('pmList', function ($scope, $cookies, $http, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

However, no matter what I do, the controller doesn't get hit. I have `otherwise` in the router, so isn't that where it should hit if all else fails?

Comment: your `otherwise` pointing to nowhere, try `otherwise({redirectTo:'/pms'});`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will hit otherwise but you can only define the redirect path into it and that redirect path will tell the url and the controller to set for the $route.current :-

```
redirectTo: '/pms'
```

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: But even if I go to /pms or /pms/outbox, it doesn't hot the controller. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a template to each route:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/pms/:box?', {
        controller: 'pmList',
        template: 'test.html'
    }).when('/pms', {
        controller: 'pmList',
        template: 'test.html'
    }).otherwise({
        controller: 'pmList',
        template: 'test.html'
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

squiroids suggestion regarding otherwise was correct, you won't see a change in your test application though.

Routing is meant to be used to navigate between regions of your application. You could have an app with two routes: pms which shows a list of PMs and pms/:box zu view a particular PM Box. The main task for ngRoute is to replace a placeholder in your application (ng-view) with a given template. Without using a template on the individual routes, your $routeProvider will not navigate as expected.

Given you have two views for the regions (pmBox.html and pmList.html), you could configure your $routeProvider zu setup routing like this: https://gist.github.com/kpko/bd0231ccefbaf8c415c7